# Can i add friction in air?

Tags: box2d

I have issue regarding speed in air. When i jump and move simultaneously that time speed of player increase.For jump i am using impuls and for movement i am using force.I want to slow speed when player is in air.

Thanks in advance

---

Following is my update method ih HUDLayer

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt :(b2Body *)ballBody :(CCSprite *)player1 :(b2World *)world
{

    if (moveRight.active==YES) 
    {   
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(maxSpeed,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
      //  ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);
    }
    else if(moveLeft.active==YES)
    {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(-10,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
    //    ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);

    }
```

}
Following is jump

```
-(void)jump:(b2Body*)ballBody:(ccTime)dt:(BOOL)touch
{
    if (touch) 
    {

        if (jumpSprte.active==YES) 
        {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
            b2Vec2 locationWorld;
        //locationWorld=b2Vec2(0.0f,98.0f);
            locationWorld=b2Vec2(0,32);
//        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
            ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(locationWorld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
      //  ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationWorld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
            ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);

        }
    }
}
```

So where i apply logic??

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28924 Perhaps this can help?

Comment: Inertia makes it harder to change velocity. It will not slow the player down which I believe is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Yes i am trying `ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);` but can not see any effect.

Comment: Well that is a ridiculously huge value for linear damping. "Normally you will use a damping value between 0 and 0.1." You should keep this handy http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [friction joint](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974). Set the two anchor points to zero so the friction doesn't have any direction. Below is vague pseudocode of how to create a friction joint and add it to your world.

Also make sure you keep the [Box2D Manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) handy.

```
var frictionJoint = new FrictionJoint();

frictionJoint.localAnchorA = new Vector2(0,0);
frictionJoint.localAnchorB = new Vector2(0,0);

frictionJoint.bodyA = yourBall;
frictionJoint.bodyB = ASquareAsLargeAsTheAreaYouNeedFrictionIn

frictionJoint.maxForce = 0.5; //This the most force the joint will apply to your object. The faster its moving the more force applied
frictionJoint.maxTorque = 5; //Set to 0 to prevent rotation

world.CreateJoint(frictionJoint);
```

Comment: How to add friction joint and which anchor point i have to set to zero??

Comment: @Diken updated answer

Comment: This code is apply in update method of HelloWorldLayer.mm?? I show you my code of jump and movement of player

Comment: No just once after you create the two necessary bodies.

Comment: But player is a dynamic body and which is define in your code as yourBall but what about bodyB??

Answer (score 3):

Unlike surface friction between solids, air friction ([drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation)) depends on the speed of the object, squared.

An easy way to model friction and drag

```
F(friction) = -k;
F(drag) = speed * speed * -k;
```

Both forces act in the opposite direction to the velocity of the object.

Notice that surface friction is a constant whereas air friction ([drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation)) must be modified each frame according to the object speed (length of velocity vector)